# Spring MVC Controller not called

Tags: java, spring, servlets, model-view-controller, dispatcher

I'm beginner in web development and try to create a simple spring mvc application.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.test.test.controller"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.test.test.model"/>

    <bean id="ViewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**controller**

```
@Controller
@Scope(value = "singleton")
public class T1Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello.do")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        System.out.print("Hi");
        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

I have written everything correct like my tutorial but still get `404 tomcat 8.5RC` error. I thing controller method is not called.

I have add `spring 4 libs` and I thing everything was fine but I don't see `Hi` output in Intellij IDEA.

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>one</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World
${message}
</body>
</html>
```

I see my `index.jsp` page when tomcat is run ... but when try to go `http://localhost:8000/hello.do` getting `404` error :(

Comment: Do you get any error or exception when you start your server?

Comment: would you please show the path of `hello.jsp` ?

Comment: Please post a link to your tutorial... Also, in `web.xml`, I see that you used `*.do` as url pattern. This means that `dispatcher` is not your default servlet... Did you properly set up thing for that ?

Comment: No , I don't get any exeption @amitmah .
hello.jsp is very simple html code and write (Hello word ) in body tag

Comment: @JasonKrs my tutorial is video and not english (persian),and ablut *.do I just follow that tutorial.

Comment: @FarshadAsgharzade, I think you have a file `hello.jsp` but where is it ? Is it under `WEB-INF` ? Give me its path

Comment: @FarshadAsgharzade, I want to see the file path of `hello.jsp`. In many case, it is under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/hello.jsp`.

Comment: @sunkuet02 inside /web/hello.jsp , behind index.jsp 
https://ibb.co/jjJZGa also I upload my route directories

Comment: I thing controller not called , because I don't see  `System.out.print("Hi");`
in Intellij IDEA

Comment: When tomcat is run, What url is shown in the `url bar` ?

Comment: @sunkuet02 http://localhost:8000/

Comment: would you please try http://localhost:8000/hello.jsp there ?

Comment: Farshad, based on the code above, it looks like perhaps you are using a very old tutorial (or else the person creating the tutorial is using some very old techniques e.g. ".do" extensions and spring XML config). Either way, I'd strongly suggest looking into a different more modern tutorial, perhaps one of the spring getting started guides. e.g.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: @FarshadAsgharzade Please even if it's in persian post the link so we can see.... There are configuration elements in you dispatcher servlet config and and you web application context config that seems odd to me...For instance, your view resolver prefix, the url pattern, the context configuration in web.xml...etc...post your link and a screen shot of your project structure

Comment: thanks for answer my question , i try all way and try other tutorial and get new exception ... I like java and Spring But can not make a simple app ... I try again .... tanks again :*

Answer (score 0):

First I would start by scanning only one base package instead of two. Remove the **controller** map from the path aswel Like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.test.test"/>
```

Get rid of the following because only one will suffice. You dont need two.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.test.test.model"/>
```

And modify your property value as follows:

```
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: still not work , remove model line and .controller ... but still get 404 error :(

Comment: @georgesvan, His `.jsp` files are not under `WEB-INF`

Comment: it must be becasue jsp's are server side pages. Everything outside web-inf are static.

Comment: @georgesvan i put it inside WEB-INF and do your new advise but still get error ,

Comment: Ok well, in my opinon, your tutorial and it's spring version are outdated. You should try another tutorial. Here you have exactly the same one: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: thanks for your solution but I can't success in this platform :(